# Fade towards bottom and object

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like the hands to fade towards the bottom and towards the text. How can I do this. The objects are Photoshop layers.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sandah Aung, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

Create a white to black gradient and paste it into the mask layer that the hands are on. White is opaque and black is transparent.